# Laravel Two Level Relation Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a DB structure...

```
Labels -> LabelPerson <- People -> Samples
```

I also have all needed relations in my Models. How can I get all `samples` ids, when I know only the `label_id`?

**Label**

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person');
}
```

**Person**

```
public function labels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Label')->withTimestamps();
}
public function samples()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sample');
}
```

**Sample**

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Person');
}
```

I try to use *hasManyThrough* relation in the `Label` model

```
public function samples()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Sample', 'App\Person');
}
```

But no result...

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'people.label_id' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: select `samples`.*, `people`.`label_id` from `samples`
>   inner join `people` on `people`.`id` = `samples`.`person_id` where
>   `people`.`label_id` = 2)",

I'm using Laravel 5.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them using `whereHas()` method, this provide you filter records by relation

```
Sample::whereHas("person.labels",function ($query) use ($label_id){
      $query->where("label_id",$label_id);
    })->get()->pluck("id");
```

Comment: Hm... And how can I get only list of samples? Realy I need only array of sample ids.

Comment: In `with("person.samples")` to `with("people.samples")`. And it is not works. Error - `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'samples.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `samples`.`id` from `labels`)`.` If remove `->pluck("samples.id")` I have got list of all my labels without any ralations (only data from labels table)

Comment: @Teretto yep, I realize that, I'm trying to find solution without using joins

Comment: @Teretto can you try above query  ?

Comment: `whereHas("people.labels"` to `whereHas("person.labels"`. And `->pluck("id")->get();` to `->get()->pluck("id")`. And it works)